# Google Chrome reports odd error when invoked from terminal

Tags: google-chrome, macbook

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on MacBook Pro 2013 Late Retina

When  I run Google Chrome from terminal,

```
me@mbp:~$ google-chrome
[9127:9127:0116/112044.353463:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[9092:9092:0116/112044.735383:ERROR:x11_input_method_context_impl_gtk.cc(144)] Not implemented reached in virtual void libgtkui::X11InputMethodContextImplGtk::SetSurroundingText(const base::string16 &, const gfx::Range &)
[9092:9208:0116/112139.106542:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(974)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for dsuggest.ydstatic.com failed err=-8181
[9092:9107:0116/112255.010817:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(408)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -118
```

it reports errors but the Chrome browser is working properly.

The identical command on another PC does not show such errors.

I am not sure whether to ignore the errors or not. My machine crashes suddenly two or three times every day since one week when I started running Ubuntu.

Regarding the specific Chrome error: What actions should I take to recover the errors?

Comment: Does it also crash if you don't use google-chrome at all?

Comment: ty, I tired firefox all these days for a testing. @DKBose Is it the usual case that ubuntu crashed on macbook. I heard that but they refer to the latest hardware.

Comment: Sorry, I have no ideas about macbooks. But my comment was more about finding whether google-chrome was to blame. But if crashes still happen without google-chrome, you'll know it's something else.